# jQuery not working after refreshing ldiv content

Tags: jquery

I know I need to use the . something like .live to get this to work but I am just confusing a h3ll here.

I have a list of data being pulled from a DB. Each Item has a form attached to it for deleting the item from the database.

OK here is the submit function for the form:

```
$(document).delegate('#delete_cat_form','submit', function() {

    var cat = $('#cat-name-imput').val(),
    id  = $('#cat-id-imput').val();

        $.post("ajax.php", {name:cat,id:id,action:'delete_cat'}, function(data){

                //Display a brief message!
                $("#message").fadeIn(3000).html(data);

                $("#message").fadeOut(3000).html(data);

                refreshMenu(); // Refresh Menu                      
            });

    return false;

});
```

The refresh menu function is this:

```
function refreshMenu(){

    $('.menu-million-dollar-wrapper').load('ajax.php', {action:'refreshMenu'}, function(data){

    });

}
```

Functions work on the initial load of the document but only once. After the ajax returns an update query from ajax.php it seems that all event handlers are gone and nothing works again.

I have tried reading some other answers that seem to be the same as might but I just can't grasp the concept for some reason.

How can I do a query for new content and display it and at the same time not loose any event handlers?

Here is what ajax.php returns when called.. This is raw but I have confirmed that it does return the same exact HTML but updated with fewer and more items

```
 <form class="edit-button" method="post" action="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'">
    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="'.$row['name'].'"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$row['id'].'"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="delete_cat"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Delete"/>
</form>
```

`$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` is not correct but should not play a role in this problem.

This is the same code that is used to initially show the form on load as well.

Comment: Can we see your html structure ? Seems like `#delete_cat_form` is getting replaced by the new content.

Comment: Not related, but you should use `$(this).serialize()` instead of `{name:cat,id:id,action:'delete_cat'}`. You would just have to keep your form up to date if you wanted to add a field for instance.

Comment: `<form class="edit-button" id="delete_cat_form" method="post" action="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'">
  <input type="hidden" id="cat-name-imput" name="name" value="'.$row['name'].'"/>
  <input type="hidden" id="cat-id-input" name="id" value="'.$row['id'].'"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="delete_cat"/>
  <input type="submit" class="delete" value="Delete"/>
  </form>`

Comment: And where is `.menu-million-dollar-wrapper` Does it wrap around this form ?

Comment: .menu-million-dollar-wrapper is the div that contains the data returned from the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing all your elements to classes instead of IDs, since you mentioned that there are more than one.

```
$(document).on('submit', '.delete_cat_form', function() {
    var self = $(this);

    var cat = self.find('.cat-name-imput').val(),
    id  = self.find('.cat-id-imput').val();
```

Comment: This makes since but why would it work when first loaded but not after the new content has been loaded

Comment: Honestly, no idea. My guess would be that IDs are supposed to be unique, so they may be handled in a special way.  That's not a very good guess though, since the way .on() works, it shouldn't care.

Comment: Thanks man.. You lead me on a wild chase that lead me to finding out what the problem was lol

I don't know if the classes where the fix but I did notice the miss spelling "imput" was not correct in the HTML. I still don't know why it work on first load but it works now.

Answer (score 0):

This is executed asynchronous:

```
$("#message").fadeIn(3000).html(data);
$("#message").fadeOut(3000).html(data);
```

At the same moment you are fading in and fading out the same message.
Instead, you should fadeOut after the fadeIn is finished.

See manula, http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/, the first parameter is callback when the fadeing function is finished.

Answer (score 0):

in jquery most everything can accept a callback function.  so instead of

```
$("#message").fadeIn(3000).html(data);
$("#message").fadeOut(3000).html(data);
```

do this

```
$("#message").fadeIn(3000, function() {
    $(this).html(data);
    $("#message").fadeOut(3000).html(data);
});
```

the stuff inside the function is executed after the fade in is complete

Comment: Thanks for this... I will change this when I am able to get the form to work correctly